# How do I return the response from cloudinary when i upload a image from cloudinary?

Tags: java, android, json, cloudinary

I'm already uploading my image to cloudinary but i don't know how to get the response and save the URL value  which has generated in order to store it in my database.
This is the code to upload it and it's working properly.

```
             MediaManager.get().upload(Uri.fromFile(filePath))
            .option("resource_type", "image")
            .option("folder", "FuegoSanto/avatar/")
            .option("use_filename", "true")
            //.option("public_id",  nombreImagen)
            .option("version","currentTimeMillis")
            .option("overwrite", true)
            .option("notification_url", "https://mysite.example.com/notify_endpoint")
            .dispatch();
```

and this is the desired response

```
                {
            public_id: 'sample',
            version: '1312461204',
            width: 864,
            height: 564,
            format: 'jpg',
            created_at: '2017-08-10T09:55:32Z',
            resource_type: 'image',
            tags: [], 
            bytes: 9597, 
            type: 'upload', 
            etag: 'd1ac0ee70a9a36b14887aca7f7211737', 
            url: 'http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/v1312461204/sample.jpg',
            secure_url: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/v1312461204/sample.jpg',
            signature: 'abcdefgc024acceb1c1baa8dca46717137fa5ae0c3',
           original_filename: 'sample'
            }
            So the idea is to take the value URL and store it in database.
```

Comment: Your response seems not an valid JSON format.

Comment: And if it was a valid JSON string, there are many JSON libraries such as `Jackson`, `Gson` or `org.json` can easily retrieve the value of field `url`.

Comment: In addition to the above suggestion, I would add that the 'version' option you're adding as one of the upload options is not actually a valid one. Version is generated automatically by Cloudinary at upload and returned in the response.
Based on your upload options you're setting a notificaiton_url and along with that you should also include the 'async' parameter otherwise no response will be sent to the notification URL. Lastly, please see this section of the documentation for relevant examples - https://cloudinary.com/documentation/android_image_and_video_upload

Comment: Francky. I see nothing about how to get the response in the documentation. I don't know how to get it.

Comment: There is an official [API](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/java_image_upload) to upload image and you can get the returned JSON object as well.